# Empty data set for CloudWatch EC2 CPUUtilization request

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I can see events for every 5 minutes using the AWS console for CloudWatch, however when using the following query:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime



stats = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    StartTime=datetime(2017, 11,1),
    EndTime=datetime(2017, 11,2),
    Statistics=['Maximum'],
    Period=300
    ],
)

pprint(stats)
```

I don't get any data points:

```
{'Datapoints': [],
 'Label': 'CPUUtilization',
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '337',
                                      'content-type': 'text/xml',
                                      'date': 'Thu, 02 Nov 2017 15:01:42 GMT',
                                      'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxx'},
                      'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'RequestId': 'xxxxxx',
                      'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  I've even been careful to specify the correct region.

Comment: Could you please inform us what exactly you receive when launch the code?

Comment: Sure, that's been done.

Comment: Could you please try `StartTime=datatime(2017, 11,1)` and `EndTime=datatime(2017, 11, 2)`

Comment: Tried that, still no data points.

Comment: The only thing that I can think about this is to add `Dimensions` inside the method parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **Eugene's** comment, including a `Dimensions` parameter value worked:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime


cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='eu-west-1')

stats = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    StartTime=datetime(2017, 11,1),
    EndTime=datetime(2017, 11,2),
    Statistics=['Maximum'],
    Period=300,
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': 'i-xxxx'
        },
    ],
)

pprint(stats)
```

It looks like the above is analogous to using the CloudWatch EC2 **Per-Instance Metrics** on the AWS console.